# Удаление части данных из документа mongoDb

Tags: yii2, mongodb

есть документ в коллекции "items":

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a074338f796316464038f35"),
"a" : true,
"b" : "text"
```

}

Как при помощи команды

```
Yii::$app->mongodb->createCommand()->update();
```

удалить "b" : "text" из документа, сохранив сам документ?

Может другая команда нужна для этого?..

Answer (score 0):

`db.collections.update({},{$unset:{b:''}}, {multi: true})`

в нативной Монге, этот запрос удалит поле `b` во всех документах коллекции

Comment: это да... но мне нужно сделать это инструментами Yii2